# Application installation Error for google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I tried installing the google chrome on my pc. after the installation is complete it starts the chrome application and gives the pop up stating that "the application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000005). Click on ok to terminate the application". This is nt exactly specific to a programming language but help will be welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its because of virus infection that i had. clean your computer by a antivirus program and re-install the chrome setup.